# How to remove request headers in HTTPS npm module

Tags: node.js, https, http-headers, npm, request-headers

I'm trying to access Google API from localhost. Chrome says that it's impossible due to origin

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api.... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I'm using `https-browserify` to make ajax request.

```
   options = {
      hostname: "maps.googleapis.com",
      port: 443,
      path: "/maps/api/....",
      method: "get",
      headers: {
        "Origin": null,
        "Referer": null
      }
    };
    result = null;
    req = https.request(options, function(res) {
      res.on("data", function(chunk) {
        return result += chunk;
      });
      return res.on("end", function() {
        debugger;
      });
    });
    req.end();
```

But this didn't help. `Origin` and `Referer` headers are still there when making this request. How can I remove them?

Comment: Chrome is complaining about a response header, not a request header.  Turning off those request headers won't help (and I don't think its possible).

Comment: @AaronDufour But why everything works when I paste this GET link in Chrome? It returns me valid JSON. I'm trying to get the same JSON from my code.

Comment: There are browser-enforced restrictions on AJAX requests to prevent data stealing.  For example, if you're logged in to gmail and another app makes a GET request, it'll be sent with your cookies and then they'll have all your emails!  Thus, the server must send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in order for AJAX requests from other domains to be allowed to get the data.  I expect that the maps api is not supposed to be used this way - you should consult their docs for proper usage.

Comment: @AaronDufour What's the difference if I deploy and launch the same code from production server? It seems that problem only in "localhost" domain name which is weird for me. Why am I not allowed to test API access from localhost?

Comment: It won't work in production, either.  The problem isn't that the domain is `localhost`, its that its different from the domain of the AJAX request (i.e. its not `maps.googleapis.com`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Origin` is considered an unsafe header by the `Request` object ([source code](https://github.com/substack/http-browserify/blob/master/lib/request.js#L144))

This is why you cannot remove them; the Request implementation only allows you to remove or modify headers that are deemed safe.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps API does have Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I could quickly tested it using the below after loading a jquery on a localhost page, it works.

`$.getJSON("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=-33.86,151.20")`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the same origin policy in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) or [the mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) !

U should use an HTTP Sniffer like [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to analyse the request!
Then u should check if the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header is present! Your request can only work from a browser when this header is present on the response! So the server, in your case the google server, has to sent it! Google will usually do this on all public APIs for in-browser use. Since else there is no way to directly acces this URL via an AJAX request.

Its important to understand that the `same origin policy`is a browser feauture build by security reasons! So it does not affect u when u make the request from a non browser enviroment like node.js or any other server side programming enviroment! Also it does not affect u when u make the request directly via the browser, since its a limitation to AJAX requests, not generall every request.

There are ways to go around this limitation, so if u have to make a AJAX request to a server that dosnt sent the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`header u can still proxy the request by your server!

Another work around is `JSONP`, but this does also support from the requested server!

Important note:
If in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is returned a origin instead of `*` the request is only possible as long you are on the origin returned by the server! So maybe the server is returning the productive origin, but denys localhost?

At least from google `reCAPTCHA` I know u can limitate a API Key to a specific origin. For development purposes normally google allows all requests from `localhost`, but maybe for any reason not in your case. The best way to check this is to analyse the HTTP traffic with an simple HTTP sniffer as said above!